# Date format converter

Tags: date, format, converters

`int`  `month1`, `day1`, `year1`, `month2`, `day2`, `year2`;

```
printf("Enter a date in the form mm-dd-yy:  ");

scanf("%d%*c%d%*c%d",  &month1, &day1, &year1)

printf(" %02d / %02d  /  %02d\n\n", month1, day1, year1);

printf("Enter a date in the form mm/dd/yy:  ");

scanf("%d%*c%d%*c%d", &month2, &day2, &year2);

printf("month = %02d  day  =  %02d   year  =  %02d\n", month2, day2, year2)
```

Have to make a date converter , getting this simple , but struggling to convert in to characters like jan feb etc.. , any tips would be apprecited

Answer (score 0):

It changes when you use capitals and maybe three letters instead of just two.

Try: MMM